# i wanted to send a json response through url so that i can retrieve it from url in android app and display it in list but my code produces wrong json

Tags: json, django, android-studio, android-volley

this is how i got when i try to print it

```
[{"model": "api.product", "pk": 1, "fields": {"productname": "keyboard", "productdesc": "keyboard is made by sony", "amount": 200.0, "available": 20, "image": "pics/Send.png"}}]
```

but i wanted it in a correct way so that i can retrieve it form the application
my django **views.py**:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core import serializers as core_serializers
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import users,product
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def viewproduct(self):
    obj=core_serializers.serialize('json',product.objects.all())

    return HttpResponse(obj,content_type='application/json')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class users(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password= models.TextField()
    email=models.EmailField()

class product(models.Model):
    productid=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    productname=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    productdesc=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    amount=models.FloatField(max_length=25)
    available=models.IntegerField()
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
```

Iam using django for backend and eclipse adt android development

Comment: Why nobody answered yet

Comment: Anyone please answer